# Image upload with Ajax but PHP does not see file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

So the PHP works fine when I just the form in a standard way.
But, when I try to send the form through ajax, it does not see the $_file[] and returns, "success|na"
which I want it to do if there is no file, but I get the same result if there is a file.

Are the ajax setting correct? cashe: false, processData: false?

Any help would be helpful guys I can always use an iframe, but I would rather not. Thank you for time!

```js
function info_save(){
 gf.wait();
 var info_ava = '';
 var info_abo = $('#info_abo').val()
 target =  './php/profile_system.php';
   $.ajax({
    url: "./php/profile_image.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData('#info_for'),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(reply){
     imgresponse = reply.split("|");
     if(imgresponse[0] == 'success' || imgresponse[0] == 'Success'){
       if(imgresponse[1] == 'na'){info_ava = ' ';}
       else{info_ava = imgresponse[1];}
       var formDataA = {
        'action': 'info',
        'info_abo': info_abo,
        'info_ava': info_ava
       };
       profile_ajax(target, formDataA,'info');
     }else{
      profile_stop(reply,'info');
     }
    }
   });
}
```

```html
<form id="info_for" class="form-horizontal col-lg-8 dblue_text" role="form" action="../php/profile_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="info_abo"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> About</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-10">
   <textarea class="form-control" id="info_abo" name="info_abo" placeholder="Let your friends know a little about yourself!"><?php echo $info_abo;?></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="file"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Avatar</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-10"> 
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<button onclick="info_save()" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>

<?php
 if(ISSET($log_username) && $user_ok == true){
  if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"])){
   $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png","gif");
   $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
   $file_extension = end($temporary);
   if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)){
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
    }else{
     if (file_exists("../profiles/".$log_username."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"])){
      echo "File Already Exists: ".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
     }else{
      $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
      $targetPath = "../profiles/".$log_username."/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
      if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)){echo 'success|'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]; exit();}
      else{echo 'Connection Error';exit();}
     }
    }
   }else{
    echo "Invalid file Size or Type"; exit();
   }
  }else{echo 'success|na'; exit();}
 }else{echo 'Please Sign In'; exit();}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FormData Constructor takes an HTMLFormElement as the parameter not a selector string or a jQuery object.

```
data: new FormData(document.getElementById('info_for')),
```

or

```
data: new FormData($('#info_for')[0]),
```

or

```
data: new FormData(document.querySelector('#info_for')),
```

Comment: Thanks so much Musa!
Actually they all worked, but
what i was forgetting was the [0].


Thanks again!