# Empty $_FILE while sending image with jQuery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file

I am trying to upload an image file to the server, but the $_FILE is always empty and I don't know why.

Here is the html:

```
    <form action='' id='ajax_form' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type='file' name='imagem'>
      <input type='submit' id='btUploadImagem' value='Upload'>
    </form>
```

And here the jquery script:

```
    function salvaImagem(){

    var form = $(this).closest('form'); 
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var dados = formData;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "salvaImagem",
        data: dados,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json"}).done(function(response)
        {
            if(response.sucesso){
                //show success message
            }
            else{
                //show error message
            }
        });
    return false;
}

$('#btUploadImagem').on('click', salvaImagem);
```

And the controller php:

```
    public function salvaImagem()
    {   
       $arquivo = isset($_FILES["imagem"]) ? $_FILES["imagem"] : FALSE;
       //some other checks
    }
```

What am I doing wrong so the $_FILE is always empty?

Comment: dataType: "json" ?? try taking that out as a test. if none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609643/image-upload-with-ajax-but-php-does-not-see-file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a plugin for manage upload. Try use [Jquery Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

But if you dont want use a plugin, try print_r($_FILES, true) to see if any informations are there

Comment: `print_r($_FILE, true)` is incorrect, it needs to be `$_FILES`.

Comment: Oups, my bad, im tired lol

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `dados.append(name, value, filename);`? Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append for details. I'm unfamiliar with the FormData Web API myself.
You might also find your answer here: [How to use FormData for ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798)